# Display pop-up with simple text upon Button click

Tags: asp.net, text, popup, onclick

I have a button placed on each row of my **GridView**. When the user presses the button I would like to display a simple popup where I show text. Part of the text is the **DataKeyName** related to the specific row.

I already tried with ModalPopupExtender **myMPE** triggered by the button and I used a Panel **myPanel** as **PopupControlID**. The problem is that the TextBox **txtPanel** of the Panel where I place the **DataKeyName** value is always empty. I tried to debug without **myMPE** and the **txtPanel** of the Panel is correctly filled. I guess it makes a mess with the postbacks.

Anybody knows a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing a manual refresh of the UpdaePanel on the modal popup panel ? If not, try manually refreshing the updatePanel & set its updateMode to Conditional.
Check above example
ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/StyleSheet.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .modal
        {
            background-color: Aqua;
            width: 150px;
            height: 100px;
            padding: 6px;
        }
        .modalBackground
        {
            background-color: #CCCCFF;
            filter: alpha(opacity=40);
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnGrid" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                </asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:GridView CssClass=".Grid-blue" ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"
                    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" InsertVisible="False"
                            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SupplierID" HeaderText="SupplierID" SortExpression="SupplierID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" SortExpression="CategoryID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="QuantityPerUnit" HeaderText="QuantityPerUnit" SortExpression="QuantityPerUnit" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="UnitPrice" SortExpression="UnitPrice" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitsInStock" HeaderText="UnitsInStock" SortExpression="UnitsInStock" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitsOnOrder" HeaderText="UnitsOnOrder" SortExpression="UnitsOnOrder" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReorderLevel" HeaderText="ReorderLevel" SortExpression="ReorderLevel" />
                        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Discontinued" HeaderText="Discontinued" SortExpression="Discontinued" />
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" runat="server" OnClick="lbEdit_Click">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" ContextTypeName="DataClassesDataContext"
            EntityTypeName="" TableName="Products">
        </asp:LinqDataSource>
    </div>
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" ID="mpeDetails"
        CancelControlID="btnClosePopup" TargetControlID="btnShowModal" PopupControlID="pnlDetails"
        runat="server">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Button ID="btnShowModal" runat="server" Text="Button" Style="display: none" />
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlDetails" CssClass="modal" runat="server" Style="display: none">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnDetails" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <label>
                    ID:</label><asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <label>
                    Name:</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnClosePopup" runat="server" Text="Cancel" /></div>
    </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.CS

> > protected void lbEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
> >         {
> >             LinkButton lbTemp = (LinkButton)sender;
>
> ```
>     if (lbTemp != null)
>     {
>         GridViewRow grow =(GridViewRow) lbTemp.NamingContainer;
>         int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[grow.RowIndex][0].ToString());
>
>         mpeDetails.Show();
>         txtID.Text = id.ToString();
>         upnDetails.Update();
>     }
> }
> ```